# How could I create a c++ function isOdd that accepts an integer array and its size and returns true is all of the array elements are odd

Tags: c++, function

```
if ( n % 2 == 0)
    cout << n << " is even.";
  else
    cout << n << " is odd.";
```

I know how to check if the numbers are odd, but unsure of how to write the rest of the code.

Comment: prefix the code with `for (auto n : v)` where `v` is your `std:.array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Or you could use std::all_of or whatever it’s called

Comment: `std::all_of( my_arr, my_arr + my_arr_size, [](int i){ return i % 2 == 1; } );`  see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isOdd(int int_arr[], int arr_size)
{
    bool is_all_odd = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        if(int_arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                is_all_odd = false;
                break;
            }
    }
    
    return is_all_odd;
}
```

You'll want to take in the array like you mentioned, the size, and traverse through it. In this case we just assume all is odd, and check for an even, if we find an even number we change the return value, stop traversing and return.